# Fitting x and y to the same dimension

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib, dimensions

I just posted a similar code but now have a different issue. how do i get x and y to the same dimension, given that ive bound y to be 0 or 1 and i want my x to take on a large set of values?

```
#Part A - Plot function against values of variable x
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as quad
import math 

#Make heaviside "theta" function
def heaviside (x): 
    if np.any(x >= 0):
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0  

#Plot
x = np.linspace(-5,5,11)
y = heaviside(x)*[1-heaviside(x-1)]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to plot the heaviside function, you may use [`numpy.heaviside`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.linspace(-5,5,101)
y = np.heaviside(x,1)*(1-np.heaviside(x-1,1))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]